# TypeError: can't cast Nokogiri::XML::Attr to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape some data and find or create a Rails object, code below:

```
@books = @page.xpath(BOOKS_SELECTOR).map { |book| Book.find_or_create_by(name: book.attribute('title'))}
```

However when this code runs I get this error:

```
  1) Error:
ScrapeHelperTest#test_scrape_page_test:
TypeError: can't cast Nokogiri::XML::Attr to string
    app/helpers/scrape_helper.rb:25:in `block in scrape'
    app/helpers/scrape_helper.rb:25:in `map'
    app/helpers/scrape_helper.rb:25:in `scrape'
    test/helpers/scrape_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ScrapeHelperTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@books = @page.xpath(BOOKS_SELECTOR).map do |book| 
  Book.find_or_create_by(name: book['title'])
end
```

Using the hash accessors `[]` on a node returns the value of an attribute rather than the `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` node returned by `#attribute`.